# How to make sure that MS Access displays the correct subreport data of the current record?

Tags: ms-access, subreports

I have a payslip main report with 3 subreports, all are linked through the employee's serialNumber:

- rptPayslipPay -for displaying regular pay
- rptPSDeds - for displaying deductions
- rptPayslipOpay - for displaying supplementary payments. This
  subreport is only showed for few selected employees.

I was able to show the total amounts of the 3 subreports on my main report's page footer. Since my last subreport rptPayslipOpay, may or may not have any data, I am displaying it in a text box named [txtOpay] like this:

```
=IIf([rptPayslipOPay].[Report].[HasData],[rptPayslipOPay].[Report]![sumOpay],"")
```

My problem is,the value of [txtOpay] shows even if the page has moved on to another employee, thus displaying the previous employee's supplementary payments to the next employee.
Is there a way to prevent this from happening?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to get it to work by fiddling around with the subreports, but assuming a 1:1 relationship between top-level report and subreport, and assuming serialNumber is a string; instead of your `IIf` statement, you might consider trying something along the lines of:

```
=DLookup("sumOpay", [rptPayslipOPay].Report.RecordSource, "serialNumber='" & [serialNumber] & "'")
```

I'm not sure exactly how your objects are named, but I think this should be close to what you're looking for.

By your description, it sounds like "sumOpay" might be a calculated field in the rptPayslipOPay report. If so, you can use:

```
=DSum("<field containing data to sum>", [rptPayslipOPay].Report.RecordSource, "serialNumber='" & [serialNumber] & "'")
```

Granted, these will run more slowly, but this might be an easier way to get it to work.

Another option is to left-join rptPayslipOPay's data from  in your top-level query, and sum it.

Comment: Thanks! The DSUM method works. Do you have any idea why my previous methods pass values to the next record?

Comment: It's hard for me to say without having the application in front of me to debug it. Do you have the "Link Master Fields" for the subreport set to sync up with the serialNumber of the parent?

Comment: Yup..I have Link Master Fields and Link Child Fields set to "serialNumber"